# This line hangs forever: authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

**My issue is:** When I use Microsoft's project, the line of code mentioned in the title runs and authenticates correctly, and I can perform operations on users as demonstrated in the "B2CGraphClient" sample project. **However** when I copy-and-paste `B2CGraphClient.cs` into my web application, this line of code hangs forever. How can this be?

The line that hangs is #184 in `B2CGraphClient.cs`.

Details:
I am using the sample project named "B2CGraphClient" mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet), whose zipfile is located [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet/archive/master.zip). The files require setting the variables `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `tenant`, which I was able to set correctly to fit my AAD B2C instance. The values of these variables were also correctly set when I copied the `B2CGraphClient.cs` code into my web app project, so I don't think that is the issue.

Clues:
These observations could potentially be the issues:

1. When running the Microsoft sample "B2CGraphClient" code, it does not require that a user authenticates into a web application; however, my web application does require a user enter his/her username/password before use of the Graph Client.
2. When the line of code in the title is run in my web application, the following is the URL in the browser: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_domain>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SiUpIn/......` I know that the `B2C_1_SiUpIn` policy name is not supposed to be in this URL. But how do I fix this?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

I am posting the code which initializes the B2CGraphClient, which shows that (at least, it looks to me) the only pieces of information that are being passed into the client in order to create its credentials are the `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `tenant` name.

```
    public B2CGraphClient(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenant)
    {
        // The client_id, client_secret, and tenant are pulled in from the App.config file
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.tenant = tenant;

        // The AuthenticationContext is ADAL's primary class, in which you indicate the direcotry to use.
        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);

        // The ClientCredential is where you pass in your client_id and client_secret, which are 
        // provided to Azure AD in order to receive an access_token using the app's identity.
        this.credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    }
```

The `credential` is later used to authenticate the graph client:

```
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(aadGraphResourceId, credential);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B2CGraphClient` has been developed for a console application.

To integrate `B2CGraphClient` in to a web application, you should change the `AcquireToken` calls from the synchronous method to the asynchronous method.

E.g. Change from:

`AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential);`

to:

`AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);`

Comment: thank you for the help. Unfortunately I'm still seeing the issue. I think the issue is that the policy name is making its way into the URL when the `AcquireTokenAsync` call is made: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_domain>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SiUpIn/......` This URL isn't supposed to include the sign up/in Azure ADB2C policy. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. `B2CGraphClient` is acquiring an access token for the Azure AD Graph API. It acquires this from the Azure AD v1.0 token endpoint that shouldn't include the policy name in the endpoint URL.

Comment: OK, cool. How do I remove the policy name and construct the correct endpoint URL? (But still keep the policy for when a user logs into the application)

Comment: Are you able to answer, please?

Comment: I suggest the `tenant` argument that is passed to the `B2CGraphClient` constructor contains the policy ID because you might be sharing this `tenant` value across both the authentication middleware and this `B2CGraphClient` class. This `tenant` argument for the `B2CGraphClient` constructor should only contain the tenant ID or name.

Comment: Thanks for continuing this thread. I have posted an update. I ran the code, and the `tenant` variable does only contain the policy ID. I also posted the code so that you can verify this. Is there something I am misunderstanding or missing?

Comment: Thank you @Emilia what are you passing as `tenant` when you initialize a `B2CGraphClient` instance? i.e. `var client = new B2CGraphClient("<clientId>", "<clientSecret>", "*what are you passing here?*")`

Comment: I am passing in `<mydomain>.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: Chris, I'm hoping you are still able to continue the conversation. Do you have any more suggestions? Is that the correct `tenant` name?

Comment: Hello Chris. I'm still hoping you may have the answer. :) This is the last time I'll ask again. :) If you could at least please let me know whether or not you know the answer, would be much appreciated. That way I know to stop writing comments.

Comment: Hi @Emilia. Apologies for not following this up earlier. It's a bit difficult for answer this from the above information. If you find me on LinkedIn, then I am happy to help with troubleshooting and we can post the final answer to here.

Comment: LinkedIn invitation sent! Thanks!

Comment: I am using                    " B2BGraphClient.AccessToken = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.aadGraphResourceId, credential); " this but facing the same issue, the line hangs forever