# Web application hangs while calling Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have developed an asp.net web application in which we perform authentication using Azure B2C and also calling Azure Graph API to fetch additional custom attributes. I am able to successfully authenticate using OpenIDConnectMiddleware. But when I try to get the user information using Azure Graph API it hangs.

`AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.aadGraphResourceId, credential);`

Comment: Are you [calling `Wait` or `Result` or any other kind of blocking method further up your call stack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am calling wait in blocking method

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue got resolved after making synchronous call instead of asynchronous call. Will there be any issue in future regarding performance or deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

should be like this right

```
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.aadGraphResourceId, credential).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this option but it still hangs while sending the request to Graph API. Below is the url it tries to redirect https://<AzureB2CtenantName>/<AzureB2CtenantName>/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/confirmed?csrf_token

Comment: I followed the steps as mentioned in below URL still I am facing the same issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314330/this-line-hangs-forever-authcontext-acquiretokenasynchttps-graph-windows-ne . @Chris Padgett , Could you please provide your input on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am calling wait in blocking method

Change that `Wait` to `await`. When using asynchronous code, you should go [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). If you don't, then you can [cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).